# Why "else" is not getting executed?

Tags: c, recursion

Why Second `printf` is printing 5 value four time instead of else block?

```
    int i=1;
    int main()
    {
       if (i<5)
       {
         i++; 
         printf("%d\n",i);
         main(); 
         printf("\n\n%d\n",i);
       }
       else
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: `else` does get executed when `i` is no longer less than 5. That's how the program ends.

Comment: Because `main` is calling itself.  Each call enters it from the top.  Once `i` is 5, the innermost call to `main` will execute its `else`.  You might want to brush up on the concept of recursion.

Comment: Calling `main` invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: Not returning a value from `main` (when `i<5`) is also undefined behavior.

Comment: @Brendan since C99 it's allowed to omit the return statement in main.

Answer (score 1):

The else block is getting executed. You would understand if you add an printf statement in the else block like this.

```
int i=1;
int main()
{
   if (i<5)
   {
     i++; 
     printf("%d\n",i);
     main(); 
     printf("\n\n%d\n",i);
   }
   else
   {
       printf("From Else Bloack, value of i is ",i);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

The else block executes when the condition of the preceding if block becomes false.

Comment: after value of i>=5 then how printf executed in if block

Comment: You will get a "5" printed, since you are incrementing the i value before printing, If you move the "i++" after the printf and before you call main(). You will get the expected output.

Comment: And also your second printf will never get executed.

Answer (score 0):

Because the `else` goes with the `if` : once the `if` is done with i<5, the `else` will never be called anymore, even if `i` reaches 5 on the i++ instruction.